# Count Backward using tail function

Tags: r

I have the following data base.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0,0,1,1),col2 = c(1,0,0,4),col3 = c(1,0,0,3))
```

And I would like to create a column which count backward to identify the second value when first >0 value appear.
So the expected answer from the data base would be 1,0,0,4 in column 4.

I have tried this but vector is returned.

```
df$Test <- apply(df[,1:3],1,function(x)x[tail(which(x>0),2)])
```

Best Regards,
Raphael

Answer (score 0):

We may need

```
x1 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[x >0][2])
replace(x1, is.na(x1), 0)
#[1] 1 0 0 4
```